# Table numbering and descriptions

Tags: tables, formatting, captions, tabularx

I am trying to add a Table number, Table caption, Table description to the following table (which was constructed with helpful inputs by @leandriis and @Dynamite)

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
%\begin{landscape}
\noindent{\small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccccc@{}} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Variable: Y}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{City-State Level} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{State-Level}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
\midrule
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
X & 0.198*** & 0.216*** & 0.141*** & 0.324*** & 0.305*** & 0.189*** \\
 & (0.0472) & (0.0399) & (0.0394) & (0.0456) & (0.0407) & (0.0374) \\ \addlinespace
X2 & 0.153** & 0.281*** & 0.282*** & 0.353*** & 0.518*** & 0.448*** \\
 & (0.0632) & (0.0627) & (0.0592) & (0.0854) & (0.0834) & (0.0718) \\ \addlinespace
X3 & 0.0577 & -0.0426 & -0.0985* & 0.0102 & -0.133* & -0.158** \\
 & (0.0555) & (0.0519) & (0.0508) & (0.0715) & (0.0693) & (0.0628) \\ \addlinespace
Number of Nonstop  &  &  & -0.0105*** &  &  & -0.00816** \\
Carriers &  &  & (0.00262) &  &  & (0.00350) \\ \addlinespace
Bus Indicator &  &  & -0.118*** &  &  & -0.148*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00936) &  &  & (0.0137) \\ \addlinespace
Other PMS Indicator &  &  & -0.0589*** &  &  & -0.0982*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00743) &  &  & (0.0101) \\ \addlinespace
Share of Passengers Traveling  &  &  & 0.129*** &  &  & 0.177*** \\
Connect, City-Level &  &  & (0.0173) &  &  & (0.0192) \\ \addlinespace
Share of Passengers Traveling  &  &  & 0.104*** &  &  & 0 \\
Connect &  &  & (0.0139) &  &  & (5.35e-09) \\ \addlinespace
Log(Population) &  &  & 0.304*** &  &  & 0.341*** \\
 &  &  & (0.106) &  &  & (0.122) \\ \addlinespace
Log(Income Per Capita) &  &  & 0.373*** &  &  & 0.318*** \\
 &  &  & (0.102) &  &  & (0.109) \\ \addlinespace
Constant & 5.043*** & 6.100*** & 5.545*** & 4.936*** & 0.636 & 2.836*** \\
 & (0.0203) & (0.249) & (0.447) & (0.0279) & (0.586) & (0.669) \\ \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
Observations & 1,237,878 & 1,237,878 & 1,209,791 & 262,534 & 262,534 & 255,173 \\
R-squared & 0.821 & 0.826 & 0.836 & 0.852 & 0.861 & 0.876 \\
Number of city-state pairs & 46510 & 46510 & 45244 &  &  &  \\
 Number of cities &  &  &  & 7190 & 7190 & 6911 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}}

%\end{landscape}




\end{document}
```

In prior tables, I had used the following codes but these codes don't seem to work with the above table.

```
\setcounter{table}{3}
\captionsetup{font=large} 
  \caption{Table Title}
           \floatfoot{\footnotesize   \begin{spacing}{0.89} This table shows... \\ 
\end{spacing} }
```

As well, the ideal outcome would look like the following picture:

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please tell us more about the desired output. Maybe a sketch could be helpful? Could you also add, which package defines the `spacing` environment or is this a user defined environment? Apart from that, you can use the usual `\caption` command if you surround the `tabular` environment from your question with a `table` environment.

Comment: Thanks @leandriis, I just added a picture. I hope this clarifies the question?

Comment: Thanks for adding the sketch.

Comment: Thank you as well!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by using the `table` environment and the `\caption` command as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass[final,3p,times,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\captionsetup{font=large} 
  \caption{Table Title}
  {\footnotesize   This table shows...  This table shows...   This table shows...   This table shows...   This table shows...   This table shows...   This table shows...   This table shows...   This table shows...   This table shows...   This table shows... }\smallskip

\centering  
\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccccc@{}} 
\toprule
& \multicolumn{6}{c}{Dependent Variable: Y}\\
\cmidrule{2-7}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{City-State Level} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{State-Level}\\
\cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-7}
 & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) \\
\midrule
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
X & 0.198*** & 0.216*** & 0.141*** & 0.324*** & 0.305*** & 0.189*** \\
 & (0.0472) & (0.0399) & (0.0394) & (0.0456) & (0.0407) & (0.0374) \\ \addlinespace
X2 & 0.153** & 0.281*** & 0.282*** & 0.353*** & 0.518*** & 0.448*** \\
 & (0.0632) & (0.0627) & (0.0592) & (0.0854) & (0.0834) & (0.0718) \\ \addlinespace
X3 & 0.0577 & -0.0426 & -0.0985* & 0.0102 & -0.133* & -0.158** \\
 & (0.0555) & (0.0519) & (0.0508) & (0.0715) & (0.0693) & (0.0628) \\ \addlinespace
Number of Nonstop  &  &  & -0.0105*** &  &  & -0.00816** \\
Carriers &  &  & (0.00262) &  &  & (0.00350) \\ \addlinespace
Bus Indicator &  &  & -0.118*** &  &  & -0.148*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00936) &  &  & (0.0137) \\ \addlinespace
Other PMS Indicator &  &  & -0.0589*** &  &  & -0.0982*** \\
 &  &  & (0.00743) &  &  & (0.0101) \\ \addlinespace
Share of Passengers Traveling  &  &  & 0.129*** &  &  & 0.177*** \\
Connect, City-Level &  &  & (0.0173) &  &  & (0.0192) \\ \addlinespace
Share of Passengers Traveling  &  &  & 0.104*** &  &  & 0 \\
Connect &  &  & (0.0139) &  &  & (5.35e-09) \\ \addlinespace
Log(Population) &  &  & 0.304*** &  &  & 0.341*** \\
 &  &  & (0.106) &  &  & (0.122) \\ \addlinespace
Log(Income Per Capita) &  &  & 0.373*** &  &  & 0.318*** \\
 &  &  & (0.102) &  &  & (0.109) \\ \addlinespace
Constant & 5.043*** & 6.100*** & 5.545*** & 4.936*** & 0.636 & 2.836*** \\
 & (0.0203) & (0.249) & (0.447) & (0.0279) & (0.586) & (0.669) \\ \addlinespace
 &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
Observations & 1,237,878 & 1,237,878 & 1,209,791 & 262,534 & 262,534 & 255,173 \\
R-squared & 0.821 & 0.826 & 0.836 & 0.852 & 0.861 & 0.876 \\
Number of city-state pairs & 46510 & 46510 & 45244 &  &  &  \\
 Number of cities &  &  &  & 7190 & 7190 & 6911 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ Robust standard errors in parentheses} \\
\multicolumn{7}{c}{ *** p$<$0.01, ** p$<$0.05, * p$<$0.1} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With this approach, tables are numbered automatically, so there is (usually) no need for commands like `\setcounter{table}{3}`.

Comment: Amazing!! You're so helpful, @leandriis. This code works like a charm!! Thanks again for all of your help. You have save a lot of time. So I am very thankful to you!!

Comment: @Job: You're welcome. Glad, I was able to help you.